# Combinatorics: Mean and Variance of an indicator function of items arranged in a circle.

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I have a problem from a homework which I've been struggling with.
I normally wouldn't post homework here, but I've spent several hours trying to understand the correct way to solve this , to no avail.
I will provide my work, and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

The problem:

```
There are 25 balls (10 blue, 15 red) arranged randomly in a circle.
Let X be a random variable who's value is the number of BLUE balls 
with a RED ball on either side of it.
    A. Find E[X]
    B. Find Var(X)
```

So here's how I did it so far:
$$
\text{Let 'Xi' be an indicator, such that:}\\
 X_i = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{1 l}
    1 & \quad \text{if the ith ball is blue, and i-1, i+1 balls are both red}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.\\ 
$$

Therefore we get E[X]:
$$
E[X_i] = \frac{15}{25} * \frac{10}{24} * \frac{14}{23} = \frac{7}{46}\\
\\
E[X]  =  \sum_{i=1}^{25} E[X_i] = 25*\frac{7}{46} = 3.804\\
$$

Now for the variance:
$$
Var(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{25} Var(X_i) + 2*\sum_{i<}\sum_{j} Cov(X_i,X_j) \\
Var(X_i) = p*(1-p) = \frac{7}{46}*\frac{39}{46} = \frac{273}{2116} \\
P \lbrace X_i = 1, X_j = 1 \rbrace\left\{  \begin{array}{1 l}
    |i-j|=1 & \quad \text{0 (since 2 blues are adjacent)}\\
    |i-j|=2 & \quad \frac{7}{46}*\frac{9}{22}*\frac{13}{21} = \frac{39}{1012}\\
    |i-j|>2 & \quad \frac{7}{46}*\frac{13}{22}*\frac{9}{21}*\frac{12}{20} = \frac{117}{5060}
  \end{array} \right.\\
\text{and since } \quad Cov(X_i,X_j) = E[X_i X_j] - E[X_i]E[X_j] \\
\\
$$
we get:
$$
Cov(X_i,X_j) = \left\{  \begin{array}{1 l}
    |i-j|=1 & \quad 0 - (\frac{7}{46})^2 = -\frac{49}{2116}\\
    |i-j|=2 & \quad \frac{39}{1012}-(\frac{7}{46})^2 = \frac{179}{11638}\\
    |i-j|>2 & \quad \frac{117}{5060}-(\frac{7}{46})^2 = -\frac{1}{29095}\\
  \end{array} \right.\\
$$

Now, we need the sum of the Covariances. To do this we need to know how many of each case there are- and this is where I'm getting confused. 
I would think we would do as follows:
We have 25c2 different possibilities where i!=j (where they can be placed).
We have 25 where |i-j| = 1, 25 where |i-j|=2 (it's a circle), and 250 where |i-j|>2.

Naively, I get: 
$$
Var(X) = 25*\frac{273}{2116} + 2*(25*(-\frac{49}{2116})+25*\frac{179}{11638}+250*(-\frac{1}{29095})) = 2.8194\\
$$

But it's a circle, so technically we have 25 ways of looking at the circle, meaning I should divide by 25 - 
but, these are not taking into account all the permutations of the 25c10 different possibilities, so I would be discounting possibilities by doing so..

I feel like this is wrong because I'm not taking into account the circle (except by allowing 25 indicators instead of 24 or 23, which is only adding possibilities and not removing them).

Help, please?

Comment: I think with a circle, all $X_i$ are equivalents, the same problem with balls on a straight line would be more difficult

Comment: confirmed by this matlab quick test:

    n=25;
    b=10;
    X = zeros(10000,1);
    for i=1:length(X)
      B = sort(randsample(n,b)); % blue balls
      C = diff([B; B(1)+n]); % differences to right neightbor clock-wise
      D = circshift(C, 1); % differences to left neightbor clock-wise
      X(i) = sum(C>1 & D>1);
    end

    E = mean(X) % 3.8182
    V = var(X) % 2.8490

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at the problem from the perspective of a ball. You are correct in that there are 3 cases for the covariance. Tweaking the function to calculate the variance of sums hopefully clarifies things. Note that the variance of a sum of stochasts is a cartesian product of covariances. Let's only use these covariances.

For each ball i, you'll need to sum:

1. once the covariance with itself (which equals variance)
2. twice the covariance with its neighbour
3. twice the covariance with its second neighbour
4. 20 times the covariance with balls further than 2 places from ball i

Summing this over all balls i results in your answer. Using the relative positions of the balls instead of indices relieves us of ambiguity on the positions of the balls in the circle.

On a sidenote: Another way of looking at this problem is: When you would construct a straight line of balls, you probably wouldn't sit on the other side of the table to conclude that you shouldn't count mirrored lines either.

Comment: Thanks for the response... unfortunately, this didn't clarify it for me.


Essentially, what you wrote is the same thing as what I did.
In other words Var(xi) + 2*(Cov(|i-j|=1)+2*Cov(|i-j|=2)+20*Cov(|i-j|>2)), for each ball (over 25 balls) is the same as 25*Var(xi) + 2*(25*Cov(|i-j|=1)+25*Cov(|i-j|=2+250(Cov(|i-j|>2), which is what I did.

So you're saying that what I did is the correct answer?

Comment: Correct. What I tried to clarify is that positions are relative, and thus you don't need to compensate for different angles in which you can look at a circle.

Comment: ah, I understand now :) thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple defensible interpretations of the question, depending on how the "random arrangement" is conducted.

#### As a multinomial problem

The red balls determine $n=15$ spaces ("slots") between them. Suppose they are filled equiprobably and independently by the $k=10$ blue balls.  $X$ counts the number of slots filled with exactly one blue ball.

To find the expectation of $X$, consider a single slot.  Let $X_i$ be the indicator of the event that that slot has exactly one blue ball.  Because the count of blue balls in that slot ($Y_i$) has a Binomial$(k, 1/n)$ distribution,

$$\mathbb{E}(X_i) = \Pr(X_i = 1) = \Pr(Y_i=1) = \binom{k}{1}\frac{(n-1)^{k-1}}{n^k} = \frac{k}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k-1}.$$

Whence, by linearity of expectation,

$$\mu_1 = \mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_iX_i\right) = \sum_i\mathbb{E}(X_i) = n\mathbb{E}(X_i) = k\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k-1}.$$

To find the variance we will need to obtain the expectation of

$$X^2 = \left(\sum_i X_i\right)^2 = \sum_i \left(X_i\right)^2 + \sum_{i\ne j}X_iX_j = X + \sum_{i\ne j}X_iX_j.$$

(The last equality follows from $X_i^2 = X_i$.)  All terms in the last sum have identical distributions.  Consider one of them:

$$\mathbb{E}(X_iX_j) = \Pr(X_iX_j=1) = \Pr(Y_i=1,\, Y_j=1).$$

The latter is the event that one ball lands in slot $i$, another in slot $j$, and the remaining $k-2$ balls in the remaining $n-2$ slots.  This is a multinomial probability given by

$$ \Pr(Y_i=1,\, Y_j=1) = \binom{k}{1,1,k-2} \frac{(n-2)^{k-2}}{n^k} = \frac{1}{n^2}k(k-1)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{k-2}.$$

Because there are $n(n-1)$ distinct ordered pairs $(i,j)$, we obtain

$$\mu_2 = \mathbb{E}(X^2) = \mathbb{E}(X) + n(n-1)\mathbb{E}(X_iX_j) = \mu_1 + k(k-1)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{k-2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

The variance of $X$ is, as usual,

$$\text{var}(X) = \mu_2 - \mu_1^2.$$

For $k=10, n=15$ compute that $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mu_1 = 5.374412$ and $\text{var}(X) = 3.226079$.

#### As a permutation problem

Suppose instead that all $(n+k)!$ possible permutations of the balls in the circle are equiprobable.  Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the $n+k$ positions indexed by the integers modulo $n+k$.  As a matter of notation, let $\text{red}(i)$ be the event there is a red ball at position $i$ and $\text{blue}(i)$ be the event there is a blue ball at position $i$.

This time let's make a position-centric analysis rather than one from the point of view of the blue balls: for each $i\in\mathcal{P}$, let $X_i$ be the indicator that a blue ball is at position $i$ and red balls are situated at positions $i-1$ and $i+1$.  The chance that $X_i=1$ is readily found by multiplying a succession of conditional probabilities:

$$\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}(X_i=1) &= \Pr(X_i=1) \\
&= \Pr(\text{red}(i-1))\Pr(\text{blue}(i)|\text{red}(i-1))\Pr(\text{red}(i+1)|\text{blue}(i), \text{red}(i-1)) \\
&= \frac{n}{n+k}\frac{k}{n+k-1}\frac{n-1}{n+k-2} \\
&= \frac{n^{(2)} k^{(1)}}{(n+k)^{(3)}}.
}$$

Here, $a^{(j)}=a(a-1)\cdots(a-j+1)$ denotes the factorial power.

As before, additivity of expectation implies

$$\mu_1 = \mathbb{E}(X) = (n+k)\mathbb{E}(X_0) = \frac{n^{(2)} k^{(1)}}{(n+k-1)^{(2)}}.$$

To obtain the variance we will need to compute the expected products $\mathbb{E}(X_iX_j)$.  These involve four distinct configurations:

1. $i=j$.  There are $n+k$ of these, each contributing $\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) = \mathbb{E}(X_i)$ to the second moment.  The total contribution therefore is $\mu_1$.
2. $|i-j|=1$: that is, $i$ and $j$ are immediate neighbors in the circle.  (The notation $|a|$ refers to the distance around the circle, which can be computed as $\min\{|\pm a + j(n-k)|: j\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$)  In this case it is impossible that $X_i$ and $X_j$ both equal $1$, so the total contribution is zero.
3. $|i-j|=2$.  These are the configurations of the form red-blue-red-blue-red.  Reasoning as before (with chains of conditional probabilities), each such configuration has an expectation of $n^{(3)} k^{(2)}/(n+k)^{(5)}$.  There are $2(n+k)$ ordered pairs $(i,j)$ with this relationship, whence the contribution is

   $$2\frac{n^{(3)} k^{(2)}}{(n+k-1)^{(4)}}.$$

   (This value is taken to be zero whenever $n+k\lt 4$, with the same convention holding for all similar expressions below.)
4. $|i-j|\gt 2$.  These are configurations of the form red-blue-red...red-blue-red.  There are $(n+k)(n+k-5)$ such ordered pairs, giving a contribution

   $$\frac{n^{(4)} k^{(2)}}{(n+k-1)^{(4)}}.$$

Consequently the variance is

$$\text{var}(X) = \mu_1 + 2\frac{n^{(3)} k^{(2)}}{(n+k-1)^{(4)}} + \frac{n^{(4)} k^{(2)}}{(n+k-1)^{(4)}} - \mu_1^2.$$

With $n=15$ and $k=10$ we obtain $\mu_1 = 175/46\approx 3.80435$, $\mu_2 = 4375/253$, and the variance is $65625/23276\approx 2.81943.$  These results agree with those presented in the question.

---

#### Verification of the results

There are several ways to check these results, including simulation and exhaustive enumeration.  To illustrate simulation, here is a check of the multinomial results. (The platform is `R`.)

```
n <- 15        # Slots
k <- 10        # Balls
n.iter <- 10^5 # Simulation length
set.seed(17)
x <- replicate(n.iter, sum(1 == table(sample.int(n, k, replace=TRUE))))
cat("Mean =", round(mean(x), 3), "Var =", round(var(x), 3))
```

The output is

> Mean = 5.367 Var = 3.2

agreeing closely with the multinomial analysis.

Here is a calculation of the full distribution of $X$ in the permutation case.  (The platform is *Mathematica*.)

```
neighbors[s_List, n_] := 
 Total[(Boole[Mod[#, n] != 0] & /@ (RotateRight[s] - (s - 1))) 
       (Boole[Mod[#, n] != 0] & /@ (RotateLeft[s] - (s + 1)))];
With[{n = 15, k = 10}, Tally[neighbors[#, n + k] & /@ 
                       Subsets[Range[n + k], {k}]]]
```

> {{0, 40380}, {1, 205100}, {2, 495950}, {3, 709800}, {4, 775775}, {5, 500500}, 
>      {6, 375375}, {7, 85800}, {8, 75075}, {10, 5005}}

That is, there is a chance of $40380/\binom{25}{10}$ that $X=0$, a chance of $205100/\binom{25}{10}$ that $X=1$, and so on.

The expectation is $\mu_1=(0\times 40380 + 1\times 205100 + \cdots + 10\times 5005)/\binom{25}{10} = 175/46$ and the second moment, computed similarly, is $\mu_2 = 4375/253$, agreeing with the analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response.
However, I don't understand how there can be 2 different results?

Surely when looking at a problem, you must assess it's distribution correctly in order to calculate the correct result. So if the results don't agree, then one of the ways to look at the problem is obviously incorrect...

Comment: also - obviously there is more than one way of looking at a problem, however, the results must still be the same, just the point of view is different.

Comment: No, that's not right.  "Random" is not a quantitative characterization: you have to specify the process involved. The problem statement does not give enough information to "assess" a unique distribution.  Both my answers are correct *given their assumptions about how the balls are distributed randomly.* One of them happens to agree with yours, but that only means it likely adopted the same assumptions you did.

Comment: what 'assumptions' are those?
The problem given provides a scenario. You can look at it any way you like, but the scenario is detailed enough such that there is only one valid way of looking at it.

If I were to say 'there are 5 balls: 3 red and 2 blue, arranged randomly in a circle. let X be the number of blue balls with a red ball on either side.' 

What's the probability now? The mean? The variance?

It's a simpler problem. Can you still come up with 2 solutions? When figuring it out by hand, is it possible to come up with 2 answers?

Comment: Yes I can still come up with two (and even more) solutions. In this post I have explained two ways of looking at the situation that are perfectly consistent with the problem. If you disagree, the burden is on you to demonstrate how one (or even both!) violate some explicitly-stated criterion in the problem statement. I would even go so far as to accept that there are some conventional *implicit* criteria in questions like this one: the obvious one is that the distribution ought to be invariant under symmetries of the configuration. That is the case in both scenarios.

Comment: Perhaps an illustration would help. In the case $n=k=2$ there are two distinguishable configurations modulo symmetries of the circle: RBRB (red-blue-red-blue in counterclockwise order) and RBBR. In the multinomial scenario both are assumed to have probability $1/2$, while in the permutation scenario they are assumed to have probabilities $1/3$ and $2/3$, respectively. [Some people have argued](http://omega.albany.edu:8008/JaynesBook.html) that absent any additional information, one should assume the maximum-entropy distribution. That's the multinomial one in this case--not the permutation one!

Comment: I see what you mean, but what type of additional information would sway it in one direction over the other? And it seems that the multinomial scenario only accounts for the different number of outcomes - i.e. there are 2 possible outcomes, so it assigns 1/2 for each - whereas the permutation scenario accounts for the probability of the outcome itself

Comment: You have hit on the crux of the matter: the question, to be unambiguous, must somehow include enough information to enable calculation of all probabilities. In some settings those probabilities are given explicitly, but usually some particular *process* whereby the randomization is achieved is described. When the process consists of placing each blue ball within one of the spaces between red balls, all with equal probability (of $1/15$), and doing so in a way that the placement of one blue ball affects no other blue balls, you get the multinomial probabilities.